# this pointer pointing to a class property which itself is a pointer

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, this, pointer-to-pointer

I was wondering why this code fails to compile with an error stating 'Member identifier unexpected in function ....' as 'this' pointer points to the individual object declared in the module itself which makes it like a hidden parameter in this case as using 'this' is vestigial if the class is stand-alone (i.e classes which do not inherit any other classes) and must not make a difference on using 'this' explicitly.

And also considering that using 'this' to point to properties which are pointers is illegal(as the compiler throws an error), why is it that the compiler only detects errors at the user-defined methods(getdata1(), getdata2(), setdata1(),setdata2()) and considers the constructors and destructors as error free ? (Well, this suggests that usage of 'this' to point to properties which are pointers is not illegal; there must be some reason behind this error.)

```
    class sampclass {
    private:
        int *data1,*data2;
    public:
        sampclass(); // constructor
        ~sampclass(); // destructor
        int getdata1() const {
            return this->(*data1); // ERROR: Member identifier unexpected in function sampclass::getdata1() const
        }
        int getdata2() const {
            return this->(*data2); // ERROR: Member identifier unexpected in function sampclass::getdata2() const
        }
        void setdata1(int data) {
            this->(*data1)=data; // ERROR: Member identifier unexpected in function sampclass::setdata1(int)
        }
        void setdata2(int data) {
            this->(*data2)=data; // ERROR: Member identifier unexpected in function sampclass::setdata2(int)
        }
    };

    sampclass::sampclass() {
    this->data1=new int(0); // assign default value of 0
    this->data2=new int(0);
    cout << "\nConstruction Successful\n";
}

sampclass::~sampclass() {
    delete this->data1;
    delete this->data2;
    //data1=NULL;
    //data2=NULL;
    cout << "\nDestruction Successful\n";
}

int main() {
    sampclass *obj=new sampclass;
    cout << "data1: " << obj->getdata1() << "\ndata2: " << obj->getdata2() << endl;
    obj->setdata1(10);
    obj->setdata2(99);
    cout << "data1: " << obj->getdata1() << "\ndata2: " << obj->getdata2() << endl;
    delete obj;
    obj=NULL;
    cout << "End of program";
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please explain me the reason behind this error thrown by the compiler ? I believe that there must be an explanation behind it.
Note that the errors are mentioned as comments; there are a total of 4 errors thrown and the program compiles and functions as required when all 'this->' is removed from code(as anticipated).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `*` is in the wrong place. In `this->X`, `X` must name a member of the class, not be some arbitrary expression. Your code makes no sense!

Write `*(this->data1)` instead. That'll give you the pointer `this->data1`, then dereference it.

Comment: The parens aren't required there; you could write it as `*this->data1`.

Comment: But here data1 is the property of sampclass and in order to access properties, this-><property name> is used, isn't it? Why does the same convention not apply to pointers? Plz explain.

Comment: @melpomene: Not if you want to keep your job :)

Comment: @hecate: The same convention _does_ apply, which is why you write it like this. The pointer variable is called `data1`, so to access it you write `this->data1`, per the formula you just gave. What you do with the resulting expression afterwards (e.g. applying `*` to dereference) doesn't factor in to it.

Comment: @hecate `*data1` is not a member of your class, the member of your class is `data1`

Comment: @hecate: I've just realised that you may think the member is called `*data1`. It is not. It is called `data1`, and has type `int*`. This is why I wish people would _stop_ right-aligning their asterisks!! http://kera.name/articles/2010/05/tomalaks-monday-monstrous-rant-i-align-your-asterisks/ Anyway, you got it right in your destructor.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Thanks for the answer, I get it now; pointer to an object's property using 'this' has the identifier name this-><pointer name>, right? Thanks again pal